# fleqn option for custom class (based off of KOMA)

Tags: math-mode, koma-script, document-classes

In the MWE below, I have a class called `test.cls` which loads `scrartcl` with the `fleqn` option. In `main.tex`, I load this class, however, the `fleqn` option seems to be lost--unless I pass `fleqn`--which I would rather not. I think the problem relates to `kpfonts-otf`. Perhaps it checks if `fleqn` was passed to the base-class and loads `amsmath`  (which is needed for align?)?

**test.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
% If I don't load kpfonts-otf (and load amsmath instead), it works
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn}{scrartcl}  % doesn't help
```

**main.tex**

```
%%% test 1: behaviour I want, but I don't want to pass fleqn
% \documentclass[fleqn]{test} % required 
%%% 

%%% test 2: "interface" I want, but fleqn seems to be lost
\documentclass{test}
%%%

%%% test 3: but if I move the contents of test.cls in here instead
% \documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
%%% it works

\begin{document}

hello.

\begin{align}
y = mx + b 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to load `amsmath` with `fleqn` before the font.

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
```